# Filling a Matrix in windows form from user input

Tags: c#, matrix, windows-forms-designer

So the problem is that I should be able to first write a value and then it should be passed but, its executing all the code at once and not giving me time to write the value i want to give it

```java
public void FillMatrix(string [,] v) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i+=2) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 4; j++) {
            lblFute.Text = "Write the number you want to put  on index " + i + " " + j;

            v[i, j] = txtVlera.Text;
            if (j == 3 ) {
                lblFute.Text = "Write the number you want to put  on index  " + j + " " + i;

                v[j, i] = txtVlera.Text;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where in this method would you expect it to wait?

Comment: after the ""Write the number you want to put  on index " , i should be able to give it a number , pass that number into the given matrix , into the specified indexes

Comment: There's no reason it should wait there. This isn't how `Label`s and `TextBox`es work. You should look into a tutorial on C# events.

Comment: I do not know what is your goal here. Maybe Console application would be better with using command Console.ReadLine(). You can use it in your loops to get user input. Or if you need to use Windows Forms application I can imagine using DataGridView to gather data from user. Or another option is to use custom InputBox in WinForms app, which is demonstrated here: https://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/.